# Javascript: Multiple filters and multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a list of multiple divs within a container:

```
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies'>
        <div class='platform-data'>DKK, USD, CZK</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry'>
        <div class='platform-data'>UK, US, France</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies'>
        <div class='platform-data'>EUR, USD, PLN</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry'>
        <div class='platform-data'>Germany, Denmark, France</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies'>
        <div class='platform-data'>SEK, GBP, PLN</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry'>
        <div class='platform-data'>Poland, UK, Spain</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="CLP">
    <div>Enter desired currency: 
        <input type='text' id='currencies' placeholder='Search Text'>
    </div>
    <div>Enter desired country: 
        <input type='text' id='countries' placeholder='Search Text'>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to allow visitors to filter platform according to currency and/or country. But I'm very new to JS and can't find the right solution.

Say you want to find pldatawrcurrencies = PLN but only where pldatawrissuesloanscountry = Poland So I enter "PLN" in the first search field and "Poland" in the second field. The result should filter out everything that doesn't contain those specific parameters.

Below is a solution I found somewhere online and tweaked. It filters according to currency only. I have tried finding a way to use two filters to no avail.

```
// Search function
var search = ('#currencies');
$(document).ready(function(){
    searchNow(search);
});

function searchNow(searchKey) {
 $(searchKey).keyup(function(){

  // Search text
  var text = $(this).val();

  // Hide all content class element
  $('.platform').hide();

  // Search and show
  $('.platform .pldatawrcurrencies:contains("'+text+'")').closest('.platform').show();

 });
}

$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
   return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you were pretty close to it ! Simply add a class for every "searchable" fields

```
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies search-me'>
        <div class='platform-data'>DKK, USD, CZK</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry search-me'>
        <div class='platform-data'>UK, US, France</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies search-me'>
        <div class='platform-data'>EUR, USD, PLN</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry search-me'>
        <div class='platform-data'>Germany, Denmark, France</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies search-me'>
        <div class='platform-data'>SEK, GBP, PLN</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry search-me'>
        <div class='platform-data'>Poland, UK, Spain</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script :

```
// Search function
var search = ('#currencies');
$(document).ready(function(){
    searchNow(search);
});

function searchNow(searchKey) {
 $(searchKey).keyup(function(){

  // Search text
  var text = $(this).val();

  // Hide all content class element
  $('.platform').hide();

  // Search and show
  $('.platform .search-me:contains("'+text+'")').closest('.platform').show();

 });
}

$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
   return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});
```

This way, you can add further `div` that are searchable or that are not. I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the the last part of the HMTL containing the search fields.

Say you want to find pldatawrcurrencies = PLN but only where  pldatawrissuesloanscountry = Poland

So I enter "PLN" in the first search field and "Poland" in the second field.
The result should filter out everything that doesn't contain those specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```js
$('input').on('input', function () {
    var currency = $('#currencies').val().toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, ''); // exclude commas
    var country = $('#countries').val().toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, '');
    $('.platform').hide().filter(function () {                    
        return $('.pldatawrcurrencies', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(currency) > -1
            && $('.pldatawrissuesloanscountry', this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(country) > -1
    }).show();
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CLP">
    <div>Enter desired currency: 
        <input type='text' id='currencies' placeholder='Search Text'>
    </div>
    <div>Enter desired country: 
        <input type='text' id='countries' placeholder='Search Text'>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies'>
        <div class='platform-data'>DKK, USD, CZK</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry'>
        <div class='platform-data'>UK, US, France</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies'>
        <div class='platform-data'>EUR, USD, PLN</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry'>
        <div class='platform-data'>Germany, Denmark, France</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='platform'>
    <div class='pldatawrcurrencies'>
        <div class='platform-data'>SEK, GBP, PLN</div>
    </div>
    <div class='pldatawrissuesloanscountry'>
        <div class='platform-data'>Poland, UK, Spain</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.

One issue, though. It doesn't work on my site. I tried creating an empty HTML file containing only this code, yet no filtering when I enter data.

Comment: Aha. The JS should be placed below the HMTL. Now it works
Thank s million. I've been struggling with this for days.